# block diagram text is not consist with normal text

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

How to write text inside of block, and the text must be consistent with normal text. The inside text font size is too smaller than normal e.g 11pt.

my source:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \hspace*{-1.5in}
    \node  at (0,0) [draw,rectangle,minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=3cm, align=left] (CP1){MA};
    \node  at (5,0) [draw,rectangle,minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=3cm] (CP2){SC};
    \node  at (10,0) [draw,rectangle,minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=3cm, align=left] (CP3){DC};
    \node  at (15,0) [draw,rectangle,minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=3cm, text centered] (CP4){Switch};
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP1) -- (CP2);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP2) -- (CP3);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP3) -- (CP4);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP4) -- (18.5,0);
    \draw (17.8,0)node[above]{Output};
    \draw [->, >=latex](-3.5,0.5) --(-1.5,0.5);
    \draw (-3,0.5)node[above]{C};
    \draw [->, >=latex](-3.5,-0.5) --(-1.5,-0.5);
    \draw (-2.7,-0.5)node[below]{M1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{tikzpicture}\normalsize`.

Answer (score 5):

In addtion to the comment by Sigur, your code still has room for improvement and I took the liberty to make some suggestions shown here. Basically, the suggestion moves (x,y) absolute coordinate method and, instead, uses `positioning` from tikzlibrary  and `right, above, below = of <reference>` skills to place the nodes. Furthermore, this suggestion defines a style for every node (with text centered) so that the code is cleaner.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows}

\begin{document}

You can change the font size inside a tikZ node like you do it in normal LaTeX. 

\tikzset{
every node/.style={text centered,draw,minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2cm,node distance=30pt}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node  [coordinate]  at (0,0.5)  (C){\normalsize C};
    \node  [coordinate,below = of C]   (M1){\small M1};
    \node  [right=of C, yshift=-0.5cm] (CP1){\Large MA};
    \node  [right=of CP1] (CP2)   {\small SC};
    \node  [right=of CP2] (CP3)   {\tiny DC};
    \node  [right=of CP3] (CP4)   {Switch};
    \node  [right=of CP4] (Output){\Huge Output};
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP1) -- (CP2);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP2) -- (CP3);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP3) -- (CP4);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP4) -- (Output);
    \draw [->, >=latex](C)node[draw=none,,above=-0.5cm]{C} -- (C-|CP1.west);
    \draw [->, >=latex](M1)node[draw=none,below=-0.5cm]{M1} --(M1-|CP1.west);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally if you don't specify the size, the fonts come out in normal size (i.e., the font size of the document). `tikz` provides a key `font` for changing the font attributes. For example if you put

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
```

The font size inside the `tikzpicture` will be `tiny` uniformly unless you over ride later.  This key has the advantage of keeping the content clean as we add it to the options of `node`.

Applying this `font` key to Jesse's code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows}

\begin{document}

You can change the font size inside a tikZ node like you do it in normal LaTeX.

\tikzset{
every node/.style={text centered,draw,minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2cm,node distance=30pt}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\normalsize]    %% not needed generally
    \node  [coordinate]  at (0,0.5)  (C){C};
    \node  [coordinate,below = of C,font=\small]   (M1){M1};            %% <-- note the options
    \node  [right=of C, yshift=-0.5cm,font=\Large,text=red] (CP1){MA};
    \node  [right=of CP1,font=\small] (CP2)   {SC};
    \node  [right=of CP2,font=\tiny] (CP3)   {DC};
    \node  [right=of CP3] (CP4)   {Switch};
    \node  [right=of CP4,font=\Huge] (Output){Output};
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP1) -- (CP2);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP2) -- (CP3);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP3) -- (CP4);
    \draw [->, >=latex] (CP4) -- (Output);
    \draw [->, >=latex](C)node[draw=none,,above=-0.5cm]{C} -- (C-|CP1.west);
    \draw [->, >=latex](M1)node[draw=none,below=-0.5cm]{M1} --(M1-|CP1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Similarly there is `text` key which is note worthy. For details refer `pgfmanual`.

Comment: ... "refer _to_"!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `refer` sounds al right to me ;)

Comment: Regardless, it's not. :)